# Simple 2D Game, Trying to Understand Multiple Classes

Tags: java

I'm creating just a simple 2D game, and I'm having troubles understanding how to interact with other classes.

For example, before now I had all of the player pictures and coordinates stored inside the main loop of the program, but now I wish to take it outside of that, into a new class. and just refer to the player as like `Player.whateverhere`

To change it.. e.g OO programming.

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/joelwmale/org.joelmale.game.darkshrine) for my full code.

```
    public int x, y;

public boolean up, down, left, right, jump;

public Image offScreen;
public Graphics d;
public BufferedImage walkAnimations[] = new BufferedImage[5];
public BufferedImage background;
public BufferedImage player;

public void run() {
    // Set Window Size
    x = 100;
    y = 100;

    try {
        // Import the images to use in the game
        background = ImageIO.read(new File("img/background.jpg"));
        walkAnimations[0] = ImageIO.read(new File("img/walkleft.png"));
        walkAnimations[1] = ImageIO.read(new File("img/walkright.png"));
        walkAnimations[2] = ImageIO.read(new File("img/walkup.png"));
        walkAnimations[3] = ImageIO.read(new File("img/walkdown.png"));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    player = walkAnimations[3];

    while (true) {

        // Create the Gravity (If player !jumping; and if player is below or above the ground, then set player to ground.
        if (!jump) {
            if (y < Character.GROUND_LEVEL || y > Character.GROUND_LEVEL) {
                y = Character.GROUND_LEVEL;

            }
        }

        // If Keys are Pressed, Move the object
        if (left) {
            x -= 2;
        } else if (right) {
            x += 2;
        } else if (up) {
            y -= 2;
        } else if (down) {
            y += 2;
        }

        // Repaint the window to update the changes
        repaint();

        try {
            // Make the thread sleep
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Catch any errors with the Thread
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

(For the people not wanting to go to the trouble of visiting my GitHub for the code); i basically want to take the x/y, and images and stuff, and put them in a new class called "Player" but having a hard time making it work (e.g by doing this.player.y or player.y)

Simply put, if you look at Alpha 0.003 update, you can see it all in 2 classes.
I've tried to move all of the player stuff, into a new class/package called `Player`

So i'd like to be able to refer to it as say: `player.x = 0;` instead of doing `x = 0;`
and same with setting animations.

I'd like to just do `this.player = walkAnimations[0]`

But I don't understand how to do it properly. Is doing `Player player = new Player();` wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you're doing is evil. Not "I murdered a baby and drank its blood evil", just the sort of affable friendly evil, like "I went to go pee during the commercial break".

So to answer the question, how should objects interact?

They should interact by sending each other messages.
In Java™ you interact by calling a method.

For instance, from a recent obligatory assignment me and another TA made, we have a [SimplePlayer class](https://github.com/Snorremd/INFO233/blob/master/Oblig2-kladding/Kjips%20Kylling/src/game/entity/SimplePlayer.java) with an illustrative example:

```
    @Override
    public void setDirection(Direction dir) {
        this.faces = dir;
    }
```

Thus if I want to tell the player object to face south, I can send it a message telling it to face south:

```
    player.setDirection(Direction.SOUTH);
```

Now, you could ask, why not just call it like this?

```
    p.faces = Direction.SOUTH;
```

Wouldn't that work?

Yes, in this and only this instance.
However, there might be other problems afoot when doing that sort of thing. Maybe the player object has to do something when he turns. Maybe it has to tell the sound system to play some noise. Maybe it has to add a number somewhere keeping track of how many steps you've taken. Maybe it has to send an email to the NSA. Who knows. And when you send the message, you don't have to care. the Player object is responsible for all of that. You are not.

This is the answer to the question "how should I interact with my objects?"

The answer to "Why doesn't what I do work?" is that the types don't match. You're trying to make the player be a BufferedImage object, which is *not* what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
"this.player = walkAnimations[0]"
```

`this.player` is a Player type variable.

`walkAnimations[0]` is a cell of a BufferedImage type array.

Therefore, the line will not compile.

Comment: So how do i go about transferring it into a new class?

Answer (score 0):

Your question wasn't very clear, but I'll try to give you general guidelines on how to approach OO game programming, since I think essentially that's what your asking.

The key thing in Object Oriented Programming is that **entities are represented by classes, and classes hold both the entity's state (the data related with it), and it's operations.**

So for example a car can be represented by a `Car` class. This class will contain what characterizes a car - it's weight, it's color, it's price, etc - and also will contain what it can do - start, drive, stop, etc.

That means that every entity in your game (be it the player, monsters, whatever) should have it's own class. And that class should contain all of the entity's info - e.g. it's position on the screen (x,y), it's image - and also anything it can do (e.g. move on the screen, jump, fire a missile).

Here is a very simple `Entity` class for example in java-pseudocode. All game entity classes should inherit from this class:

```
class Entity{

    private int x, y; // position on screen
    private int dx, dy; // this is how much the entity moves each game-loop cycle.
    private Image image;
    private Rectangle boundingBox;
    private int healthPoints;

    public Entity(int x, int y){

        // ths position of the thing is set through the constructor
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;

        healthPoints = 100;

        Image = new Image(/*some file*/); // this is pseudo code.
        boundingBox = new Rectangle(image); // pseudo code. A rectangle the size of the image.

    }

    public int getX(){ return x; }

    public int getY() { return y; }

    public Image getImage() { return image; }

    // user input can affect this from the outside, to move the entity. or possibly an ai mechanism.
    public void setDX(int dx){ this.dx = dx; }
    public void setDY(int dy){ this.dy = dy; }

    public void move(){
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

    public Rectangle getBoundingBox(){ return boundingBox; }

}
```

Any object derived from this class will hold *for itself* all of it's data and operations.

Now, your gameloop control manages the entities from the outside and access their data - to move them, check for collisions, display their image, etc.

For example, a very simplified game class holding the game loop. In *pseudocode* (this is one approach, but it's good to start with something similar):

```
Class GameClass{

    ArrayList entities;

    public GameClass(){

        entities = new ArrayList();
        startGameLoop();

    }

    private void startGameLoop(){

        while(true){ // this is bad, don't do this.

            displayEntities(); // step 1 of gameloop.
            moveEntities(); // step 2
            checkForCollisions(); // step 3

        }

    }

    private void displayEntities(){

        for(int i=0; i<entities.size(); i++){
            Entity entity = entities.get(i);
            displayImage(entity.getImage(),entity.getX(),entity.getY());
        }

    }

    private void updateEntities(){

        for(int i=0; i<entities.size(); i++){
            Entity entity = entities.get(i);
            entity.move();
        }

    }

    private void checkForCollisions(){

        for(int i=0; i<entities.size(); i++){
            Entity entity = entities.get(i);

            for(int j=0; j<entities.size(); j++){
                entities.remove(i);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

This is missing ofcourse logic to get user input. What you can do is for example when the user presses the right arrow, set `character.setDX(2)`, and left arrow will be `character.setDX(-2)`. Remember that `dx` is the value added to `x` every cycle, when `move()` is invoked. This is one approach.

It's also missing tons of other things.

It's impossible to cover all of the basics in this one post. But just remember one thing:

**All entities are encapsulated in classes, that hold their own data and operations. Have a central class to manage it all, contating a game loop.** Also classes can have methods to interact with other classes.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: [Also, here's a series of tutorials that helped me a lot when I was starting out.](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/)